# Create a formula in Excel to search if two conditions are met then it return a 1

Tags: microsoft-excel

My excel sheet is for measuring occurrences of injuries within sport. I want to show how many specific injuries occurred across the team. E.g. 10 head injuries happened across the squad of players. I have played with IFs and Counts but can't seem to get it to work. The "result" sheet is on a different tab to the "data" sheet if this makes a difference

Data table

```
POSITION    PLAYER  Code    Region


PROPS   A Prop  HHOO    Head Injury
    A Prop  HZEX    Head Injury
    B Prop  HZNM    Head Injury
    B Prop  HZNM    Head Injury
    C Prop  NKXX    Neck Injury
```

Results table

```
Musculoskeletal Injuries    
Region            Players effected by injury
Head Injury       #REF!
Neck Injuries   
Shoulder Injuries   
Upper Arm Injuries
```

So under Head injury it should say 2 for B Prop

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data and your expected output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Count number of injuries with [count formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNT-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c).

> ```
> Syntax
>
> COUNT(value1, [value2], ...)
>
> The COUNT function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> value1    Required. The first item, cell reference, or range within which you want to count numbers.
>
> value2, ...    Optional. Up to 255 additional items, cell references, or ranges within which you want to count numbers.
> ```

2. Use [If statement](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) in a way suitable for your data.

> ```
> Syntax
>
> IF(logical_test, value_if_true, [value_if_false])
>
> For example:
>
> =IF(A2>B2,"Over Budget","OK")
>
> =IF(A4=500,B4-A4,""
>
> Argument name
>
> Description
>
> logical_test    (required)
>
> The condition you want to test. You can nest other logical functions within this argument, including AND, OR and XOR functions.
>
> value_if_true    (required)
>
> The value that you want returned if the result of logical_test is TRUE.
>
> value_if_false    (optional)
>
> The value that you want returned if the result of logical_test is FALSE.
> ```

Note: If you want to select data from different tab inside the formula, then try this: first write your formula and click on variable you need to change, then select different tab and select specific cell(s) related to formula.

If you provide your data, I can bring more details regarding to your problem.

Comment: Great thanks for your help so far. My data includes a list of players: Player A, Player B, Player C etc on one tab. They all having varying injuries based on predefined codes that I have created. Eg a Head injury is HI, Wrist WI with added letters for specific issues. One tab lists all the players with the specific injuries eg Player A HI, WI They may have the injury reoccurring but also many players having the same injury, the area I want to find out. So ultimately my cell wants to show how many head injuries in total across the whole team, excluding if someone has had it multiple times

Comment: Hi matt, as it said before, you should bring an example of your data by editing your post

Comment: Data Table - Player A - HI, WI, LI1, HI, HI, Player B - HI, WI, HI. Player C WI etc. I want to show on another tab that there are two players effected by head injuries. So my result would be 2. Not simply just showing a count of all head injuries. Hope this helps clarify?

Answer (score 0):

A trivial and understandable solution for two conditions:

```
 Help1     
 if condition met then 1 else 0

 Help2     
 if condition met then 1 else 0


 result
 =Help1 * help2
```

If both condtions are met than both (all) fields will be 1 and the result of the multiplication will be 1. If any condition is not met then the answer will be 0.

[image: Example]

This is a very generic solution and there are likely much better ones. But unless you add more details in the post we do not know precisely what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ugh. It does help it I cut and paste the cells. As it is the screenshot still has an error in it and I already close excell. he idea is clear though.